# What place is this quote referring to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, definition

What is "**Bankers' row and sleight of hand at Seventh Avenue fashion houses**" referring to?

I searched Google Maps for Seventh Avenue and 6 Seventh Avenue in the US, awkward.

[image]

Comment: Those are not literal addresses. The author writes of "boondoggles *(useless projects)* on bankers' row", and of "sleight of hand *(magic tricks)* at 7th Avenue fashion houses."

Comment: So its only nonsense jargon?

Comment: It is not nonsense, but illustrative. General examples of the financial stories that the author has covered.

Comment: Bankers' row means a street with banks?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but more generally. For example "Wall Street" might refer to stock market trading, though they might not actually be on Wall Street, New York. So "on bankers' row" just means "in the world of banking".

Comment: It is referring to New York city. Seventh Avenue runs through the middle of what is known as the Garment District there. New York is both the fashion and banking center of the US. By the way, there are probably thousands of streets named Seventh Avenue in the US; there are many more than 6.

Comment: A que se refiere x = What is x referring to?]

Comment: @Jeff Morrow yeah It's kinda tricky but I suppose to know which place is referring to I need to know a little about the culture in NY.

Comment: bankers' row is not New York necessarily. It's referring to the big banks and what they do. Sort of sarcastic.

Comment: Big Banks? What do you mean? Where they are located anyways? Elite Baks?

Comment: the big banks, like big pharma. The largest banks that control everything financially, basically. Seventh Avenue in NYC is the heart of the garment district where clothes are made and fashion designers have their offices.

Answer (score 1):

Boondoggles on bankers row means the tricks bankers play on investors to get them to put their money low return investments. Bankers row here refers to banks in general.
Slight of hand at Seventh Avenue Fashion houses refers to how these high fashion houses are skilled at deceiving customers and giving them low quality goods which are purportedly good.